# Overlay Chrome Extension Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I am working on a chrome extension that would display an overlay over any tabs the user is working on. I need it to operate within the full viewport.

I'm using vanilla javascript and content script to inject a full viewport-size div (*to the body since I want it to be used on any website*) and then append my template to the div I created and injecting them with Angular. It works very well.

## The Problem

However, this overlay is somewhat blocking since the div I create has to have a z-index of at least 0 to be seen. Let's imagine you perform a google search, you will be able to search since the google search bar has z-index > 0 but you won't be able able to click on the results ... The problem appears in pretty much any website.

Now I tried to play with z-index: I apply z-index = -1 so I won't see the main overlay div but the problem with that is that the content I append to it seems to inherit the z-index -1 no matter what so I never see my template!

I've followed quite some topics here but I didn't find an answer to my problem!

## The Question at last ...!

**How do I create a  non-blocking chrome overlay ? :)**

*Remember:* I need to be able to interact with the overlay at any given moment, not simply when I click on the icon related with the BrowserAction!

Comment: CSS style with `pointer-events: none` might be what you're looking for. See also [pointer-events:none but capture click](//stackoverflow.com/q/34037649)

Comment: It seems it will do the trick. I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm It works perfectly :)

Comment: Add an answer and describe your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is simply to add the css property

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

to the main div and

```
  pointer-events: auto;
```

to the template